# AWS CLi; Revoking default security group ingress rule results in an error

Tags: aws-cli, network-security-groups

I've been asked to figure out how to create items in AWS via CLi for future automation later.  I'm stuck on the Security Groups.  I can create one fine and I can add ingress rules no problem but I noticed that the default group that gets created has an ingress rule of All Traffic Any/Any and references the SG as the source.

I want to remove this as a possible vector for security risk.  I get an error saying the rule doesnt exist.  I have tried with the SG group id, group name even using the ip permissions syntax and it all results in the same error.  I dont see a way to edit the ingress rule either.  Has anyone done this successfully?

Of course the GUI is uber simple and it works fine, I just need to know the proper syntax to do this programatically.

Comment: Could you post the CLI command you tried?

Comment: tried this:  aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --profile us-west-1 --group-id sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXc --protocol all --cidr 0.0.0.0/0. And i also tried this:  aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --profile us-west-1 --group-id sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXc --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "-1", "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"}]}]'. Both result in the following error: " An error occurred (InvalidPermission.NotFound) when calling the RevokeSecurityGroupIngress operation: The specified rule does not exist in this security group."

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to get the output of the current rule via `describe-security-groups` and then pass it in as a parameter to `revoke-security-group-ingress`. This way, the rules match exactly.

First, this command extracts the existing Inbound permissions:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxx --query SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[]
```

The output looks like:

```
[
    {
        "FromPort": 0,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
        ],
        "Ipv6Ranges": [
            {
                "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
            }
        ],
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "ToPort": 65535,
        "UserIdGroupPairs": []
    }
]
```

Then, embed that command in the `revoke-security-group-ingress` command:

```
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-xxx --ip-permissions "`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxx --query SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[]`"
```

(This worked on my Mac. If you are running Windows, run it under the Ubuntu shell.)

Comment: I'm using a mac as well.  when i try i get the error.  zsh: no matches found: SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[].  My command:  aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx --query SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[].

Comment: aws ec2 describe-security-groups --profile us-west-1
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1", 
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"

Comment: "Description": "default VPC security group", 
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1", 
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "IpRanges": [], 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "x", 
                            "GroupId": "sg-x"

Comment: Try the `describe-security-groups` command without specifying a `--query` to see what output is being provided. It sounds like your shell is doing strange stuff to the command, since `zsh` should not be complaining. Make sure it returns a result similar to what I've shown above before combining the commands. Feel free to add your errors/debug to your Question so it is nicely formatted.